# x:Bind in windows 10 Mode One way

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-10

I am trying to update the list which is Bound to ListBox , When the scroll bar reaches end.I need to update the list and show the changes in UI also.Here it is not updating automatically.Can someone please help me in fulfilling my requirement.

If i tried to use TwoWay mode, It shows below error:

Error : Invalid binding path 'itemsList' : Cannot bind type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(System.String)' to 'System.Object' without a converter

```
 <ScrollViewer
            x:Name="sv"
            ViewChanged="OnScrollViewerViewChanged">

            <ListBox x:Name="listView"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Height="Auto" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="172"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind itemsList, Mode=OneWay}"/>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

and the code

```
     public List<String> itemsList = new List<string>();

     private void OnScrollViewerViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    var verticalOffset = sv.VerticalOffset;
                    var maxVerticalOffset = sv.ScrollableHeight; //sv.ExtentHeight - sv.ViewportHeight;

                    if (maxVerticalOffset < 0 ||
                        verticalOffset == maxVerticalOffset)
                    {
                        // Scrolled to bottom

                        Util.debugLog("REACHED BOTTOM");
                        int i;
                        //   itemsList = null;
                        itemsList.Clear();
                        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                        {
                            itemsList.Add("Item number " + i + 900);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Not scrolled to bottom
                        //   rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here(In below link) is the answer for my question.Thanks alot for all who tried to answer my question.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c730558-f933-4483-8d5b-1710d19f99de/xbind-in-windows-10-mode-one-way-i-am-trying-to-update-the-bind-list-when-scrollview-reached-to?forum=wpf